# Disable RichTextBox newline auto-formatting

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have been trying to make effective editor with syntax highlighting in WPF RichTextBox for a while now, and so far it was really painful experience. Now I have encountered another problem:

When user presses enter key or when the binding loads text, RTB adds some kinds of paragraphs I guess, and renders the newline characters useless for me. I want to have all newline chars in string representation (\n, \r, etc.) and without paragraphs. My guess is that there is an easy way to disable automatic RTB formatting, but I am unable to find it.

Of course, there are numerous workarounds for this (for example when `InsertTextInRun("\r\n")` is used, the automatic formatting isn't applied), but I would like to simply disable auto-adding of paragraphs. Hope someone can help.

Comment: I would like to know why people edit WPF RichTextBox to RichTextBox. That's the reason why you can't find valid resources on Windows.Controls.RichTextBox, as it is not the same as Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.

Comment: I would guess, because at Stackoverflow its not good to have certain words in the question itself, most of these are the same as tags. Mostly because its redundant. And WPF was already in your Tags, and it gets filtered that way in SO.

Comment: @dowhilefor There is a point in things you said, but the question itself is the first thing people see, so why risk them finding what they think is a wrong answer. Well, I guess RTB is a bit too specific case to be discussed.

Comment: @DejanMaksimovic have you found your answer? I have a similar problem right now.

Comment: I don't remember finding an answer to this, it was probably my bad or I eventually switched to always setting `Text` property in `TextRange`. I checked and I don't see I ever used mentioned `InsertTextInRun` workaround. If you find a solution be sure to write an answer. I will gladly accept it for anyone that gets stuck on the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the margin is 0, the auto-format is disable. See the xml code below

```xml
   <RichTextBox ...>
        <FlowDocument/>
            <RichTextBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                </Style>
            </RichTextBox.Resources>
    </RichTextBox>
```

Comment: Explain your solution.